# What did the blacked-out text actually say?

Tags: i-kill-giants

In *[I Kill Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Kill_Giants)* the main character (literally) blacks out things that she doesn't want to hear which is, presumably, anything about

> her mother dying of cancer

I can make out "*Your Mother*" in at least one of the panels but the others are a complete mystery.

[image]

[image]

Is there any official confirmation what's behind the blocking? A transcript would be ideal.

Comment: FYI - If you can find a pdf version of this it may be possible to select the text and see what was hidden underneath. I have done that before.

Comment: @Odin1806 - I've tried that with multiple versions. These images are static rather than dynamic.

Comment: It is also sometimes possible to open the image in an image manipulation program and play with levels to get something usable. Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: @user3757614 - I've used every trick I can think of to tease out any detail. Unfortunately, there's really no good way to lighten something that's been drawn directly over an image, then rescanned.